# Creating XML Document from XSL Schema

Tags: xml, document

Does anyone know a better way of creating XML Document from XML Schema?

Comment: I take you mean "XML Schema", not "XSL Schema"?

Answer (score 0):

There are several tools available that you can use to easily generate instance XML documents from an XML Schema.  To name a few:

- [Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wst.xmleditor.doc.user/topics/tcrexxsd.html)
- [oXygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/demo/GenerateSampleXMLFiles/generateSampleXMLFiles.html)
- [Stylus Studio](http://www.stylusstudio.com/xml_generator.html)